# Correct behavior of Integrate involving logarithmic cut, or possible bug?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.4.0**

---

I just discovered that `Integrate` with simple poles in its integrand sometimes gives different results depending on number type of its limit (Exact vs Inexact).

```
(*Approximate upper limit*)
Integrate[1/z, {z, -1 - I, -1 + .5 I}] // N
```

> `-0.235002 + 5.03414 I`

```
(*Exact upper limit*)
Integrate[1/z, {z, -1 - I, -1 + 1/2 I}] // N
```

> `-0.235002 - 1.24905 I`

The second result is the one that everyone would agree with as it properly accounts for crossing the logarithmic cut running along the negative axis.

Two questions:

1. Is this the correct behavior of `Integrate`?  I can't seem to find this behavior mentioned in the documentation.
2. I have a *huge* Mathematica notebook (containing some 35 `Integrate` calls) that is supposed to compute integrals symbolically and/or numerically depending on the type of its limit.  e.g. of the form:

   ```
   f[a_,b_] := Integrate[1/z, {z, a, b}]
   ```

   What would be some quick ways to get around this bug?  I noticed `NIntegrate` correctly accounts for the branch cut, but it only works if there's nothing symbolic left.

Comment: What happens if you do `Integrate[1/z, {z, -1 - I, -1 + t I}] /. t -> {1/2, 0.5}`?

Comment: @J.M. The initial Integration step takes forever and finally gives a `ConditionalExpression`.  After replacing, you get `Undefined` for both cases.  (btw you can't do your replace-list trick when there is a `ConditionalExpression`)

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau With *Mathematica*'s branch-cut convention for `Log`, isn't $\int_a^b \frac{dx}{x} = \ln(b/a)$ always true for any $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$?  What's the deal with all the `CondintionalExpressions` that it spits out?

Comment: Maybe. But `Integrate` is not going to figure out that that always corrects for `Log[b]-Log[a]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Then instead of releasing versions of Mathematica with garbage functions like `ReIm` and `AllTrue`, maybe they focus their attention on `Integrate`.  Ok, that made me feel better.

Comment: Honestly, it didn't do much for me. Regardless of what development directions you like or don't like, the impact of resource allocation on `Integrate` is not likely to be huge. There is ongoing work there, and the possibility of improvements. Also the possibility of breakage. It's pretty close to a no-win situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These integrals in the complex plane are ambiguous in that the paths are not specified.  Perhaps, the first `Integrate` to the long way around `z = 0`, as in

```
Integrate[1/z, {z, -1 - I, +1 - I, +1 + 1/2 I, -1 + 1/2 I}] // Simplify
(* 1/4 I (7  π - 4 ArcTan[1/2] + I Log[64/25]) *)
% // N
(* -0.235002 + 5.03414 I *)
```

The same result is obtained from

```
Integrate[1/z, {z, -1 - I, +1 - I, +1 + .5 I, -1 + .5 I}]
```

The only way I know to be sure that the desired path is taken is to express the integral as

```
I Integrate[1/(-1 + I y), {y, -1, .5 }]
(* -0.235002 - 1.24905 I *)
```

Comment: Well, I thought that in a computer program like Mathematica, one would have a consistent convention which would most naturally be straight path.  If Mathematica just picks whatever contour it wants, I would call this a catastrophic design flaw.

Comment: @QuantumDot  I would think so too, but I am unable to find a discussion of this point in the documentation.   Contour integrals are so common that they should be covered explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

This bug has been fixed as of Mathematica [10.4.0](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn104.html).

```
Integrate[1/z, {z, -1 - I, -1 + .5 I}]

(* -0.235002 - 1.24905 I *)
```